# Add event to Google Calendar using GNOME Calendar

Tags: sync, gnome3, google-calendar

I have installed GNOME Calendar, but even though it loads my events from Google Calendar (added through Online Accounts), I can't make a new event and save to Google Calendar. It just saves to the local calendar. How can I add an event to Google Calendar using GNOME Calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out.

When you add an event,

1. Click on the "More Details" button.
2. Click on the coloured square. From there, you can choose the calendar to add it to.
3. Fill in the other details for your event.